# Firebase authentication with facebook test users on Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have setup firebase authentication with facebook.
I can authenticate correctly with a real user, but when I try to log in with a facebook test user (the ones created in facebook console), the login process fails silently, and no firebase user is created.
I am using firebaseui-auth but I don't think this is the problem.
I've heard that firebase does some sanity checks on the account, so I believe it is picking up that the email address does not exists and the authentication fails.
Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: I have the exact same problem.